# Which method to use to search huge records QueryAsync or Query in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

say, I have a huge records built up over the months,so which method to use?

1.Is there a speed different when the transactional record size is huge for the below?

2.If below not good. What method to use to search thru say more than 10 000 records which contain only customer details like name, addr, contact or others.

3.What is the record size that I should think about back up the existing database and re-create a new one after deleting the old one.

```
1) QueryAsync

var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DBPath);

var allitems = await db.QueryAsync("Select * From Customer Where CompanyName ='" + Class1.Company + "'" + " AND No ='" + No + "'");


2) Non Async

var db = new SQLiteConnection(DBPath);

var allitems = db.Query("Select * From Customer Where CompanyName ='" + Class1.Company + "'" + " AND No ='" + No + "'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fine using only `Query`. `QueryAsync` will probably not provide much, if any boost in performance.

10,000 records is not very many, so your query should be quick. If have not already, you can create an index on the `Customer` table, which will hugely speed up the query.

For example...

`CREATE INDEX CompanyNameNo ON Customer (CompanyName, No)`

Check out http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html for information on indexes.